# где находятся переменная в стеке или в куче?

Tags: c++, c

ребята , не пинайте строго. вопрос дилетанта. Если я не пользую маллок, а просто тупо таким образом инициализирую jjj, тогда где хранятся a и b для jjj в куче или в стеке ?

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
    int b;
} myStruct;


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    myStruct* jjj;
    jjj->a = 777;
    jjj->b = 111;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Если на вопрос дан исчерпывающий ответ, то не забывайте поставить галку слева от него, чтобы он не простаивал без принятого ответа

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нигде. Потому что на данный момент, указатель `jjj` никак не инициализирован. Программа упадет на 2 строчке.

Answer (score 3):

Формально - по адресу, хранящемуся в `jjj`. Но какой там адрес хранится - никто ничего не скажет, потому что это *неинициализированная локальная* переменная.

Так что адрес может быть каким угодно, только вот с огромной вероятностью - таким, куда писать/читать нельзя. Тогда ждет аварийный останов программы.

Вот так - совсем другое дело:

```
myStruct* jjj = new myStruct;
jjj->a = 777;
jjj->b = 111;
```

Comment: я ошибся в постановке вопроса. разумеется абсурд сморозил. сейчас поставлю другую